# Appending cat to command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, cat

I have a script to retrieve the mac address but its not returning the command properly.

```
chromium-browser --noerrdialogs --disk-cache-dir=/dev/null --no-first-run --ignore-certificate-errors --test-type --kiosk \"http://x.com/getscreen?mac=$(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address)\""
```

Is there something im doing wrong I want it to use the output of the cat command as a string

Comment: As indiciated by @exe, you have an extra double quote at the end.  I would recommend though instead of using that particular file, which may not always be `eth0`, to do something like... `ifconfig | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}' | sed -n 1p` which will grab the mac address of the first interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you tipped an extra **"** at the end of the command line.

Cheers